# Flutter sorts two lists instead of one

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hi :) I need help with flutter, I am new to this whole thing.
I want to sort a list `allGames` but it automatically sorts the list `chartGames`, too. How can I separate those two which are not connected at all?

```
class _GameHistoryScreenState extends State<GameHistoryScreen> {
  Future resultsLoaded;
  Future chartResultsLoaded;

  List<Game> allGames = [];
  List<Game> chartGames = [];

  List<Game> incompleteGamesList = [];

  List<Game> completeGamesList = [];

  String dialog;

  bool loading;

  double averageScore;

  double averagePuttsPerHole;

  double averageDerivationPar;

  final String route = GameHistoryScreen.routeName;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    loading = true;
    resultsLoaded = getUsersGamesSnapshot();
    chartResultsLoaded = getUsersGamesSnapshotChart();
  }

  // Gets all games of the user
  Future getUsersGamesSnapshot() async {
    var data = await Provider.of<GameProvider>(context).games;

    setState(() {
      allGames = data;
      loading = false;
    });
  }

  Future getUsersGamesSnapshotChart() async {
    var chartData = await Provider.of<GameProvider>(context).games;

    setState(() {
      chartGames = chartData;
      loading = false;
    });
  }

  static const menuItems = <String>[
    'Datum',
    'Platzname',
    // 'Score',
  ];
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropDownMenuItems = menuItems
      .map(
        (String value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        ),
      )
      .toList();

  String btn1SelectedVal = 'Datum';

  void sortList() {
    switch (btn1SelectedVal) {
      case "Datum":
        {
          allGames.sort(
              (game1, game2) => game2.startTime.compareTo(game1.startTime));
          break;
        }
      case "Platzname":
        {
          allGames
              .sort((game1, game2) => game1.courseId.compareTo(game2.courseId));
          break;
        }
      // case "Score":
      //   {
      //     allGames.sort((game1, game2) => game2.strokes.compareTo(game1.strokes));
      //     break;
      //   }
    }
  }

  //  für jedes Element von Games wird der Konstruktor von ChartData mit dem Index und den Daten
  //  aufgerufen. Dieser wird in einer Liste gespeichert und am Ende zurückgegeben
  List<ChartData> createChartList() {
    List<ChartData> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < chartGames.length; i++) {
      list.add(ChartData(i, chartGames[i].endScore.toDouble()));
    }
    return list;
  }

  void getButtonNumbers() {
    int holeCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chartGames.length; i++) {
      this.averageScore += chartGames[i].endScore;
      for (int m = chartGames[i].startHoleNumber;
          m <= chartGames[i].endHoleNumber;
          m++) {
        this.averagePuttsPerHole +=
            chartGames[i].strokes.getPuttsByHoleNumber(m);
        holeCounter++;
      }
      // this.averageDerivationPar += blub;
    }
    this.averageScore = this.averageScore / chartGames.length;
    this.averagePuttsPerHole = this.averagePuttsPerHole / holeCounter;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    sortList();
    return MainScaffold(
      title: "Game History",
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () => {},
                    child: Column(
                      children: [Text("blub"), Icon(Icons.score)],
                    )),
                OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () => {},
                    child: Column(
                      children: [Text("blub"), Icon(Icons.sports_golf)],
                    )),
                OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () => {},
                    child: Column(
                      children: [Text("blub"), Icon(Icons.departure_board)],
                    )),
              ], //"ØScore"
            ),
          ),
          Container(
              height: 200,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: SfCartesianChart(
                primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
                series: <LineSeries<ChartData, int>>[
                  LineSeries<ChartData, int>(
                      animationDuration: 5000,
                      // Bind data source
                      dataSource: createChartList(),
                      xValueMapper: (ChartData sales, _) => sales.number,
                      yValueMapper: (ChartData sales, _) => sales.data)
                ],
              )),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Filtern nach:'),
            trailing: DropdownButton<String>(
              // Must be one of items.value.
              value: btn1SelectedVal,
              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  btn1SelectedVal = newValue;
                });
              },
              items: this.dropDownMenuItems,
            ),
          ),
          ...allGames.map<Widget>(
            (game) => Card(
              elevation: 5,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 5,
                horizontal: 5,
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                    child: FittedBox(
                      child: Text('${game.endScore}'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                title: FutureBuilder(
                    future: Provider.of<CoursesProvider>(context)
                        .getCourseById(game.courseId),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        final course = snapshot.data as Course;
                        return Container(
                          height: 25,
                          width: 100,
                          child: AutoSizeText(
                            course.name,
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflowReplacement: AutoSizeText(
                              "Error: Name too long",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Text(" ");
                      }
                    }),
                subtitle: Text(
                  DateFormat.yMMMd().format(game.startTime),
                ),
                trailing: Container(
                  width: 105,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      2 > 1
                          ? Icon(
                              CustomIcons.singleplayer.icon,
                              color: Colors.deepOrange,
                            )
                          : Icon(
                              CustomIcons.multiplayer.icon,
                              color: Colors.deepOrange,
                            ),
                      game.completed
                          ? Icon(
                              Icons.check_box,
                              color: Colors.green,
                            )
                          : Icon(
                              Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
                              color: Colors.green,
                            ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            // makes no sense but fixes an issue
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.number, this.data);
  final int number;
  final double data;
}
```

My flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

the reason when you sort `allGames`, other lists get to change too is that you are sharing the reference to the original list in your `GameProvider` class.

you should create a shallow clone of your list. you can do it like this:

```dart
setState(() {
      allGames = [...data]; // create a new
    });
// ...
setState(() {
      chartGames = [...chartData]; // create a new
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the two lists with the same expression, so they are in fact the same (`await Provider.of<GameProvider>(context).games;`). You could create two separate lists in your provider. Or you could create a getter that returns a sorted/filtered version of the list directly.